# Separating strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string that's a couple of hundred characters long and contains

```
str= "... a OUTPUT b ..."
```

where `a` and `b` are the beginning and the end of the `OUTPUT` I need.

Now, I want to search for the `a` part in that long string and copy the content between `a` and `b` -- `OUTPUT` (which doesn't have a fixed number of characters) into a new string, but I can't find the way to do it.

To make things slightly more complicated, that `a OUTPUT b` part is going to appear multiple times in that string, so I figured out it should only look at the first occurrence. Then, I'll shorten the string and repeat the process.

Little help?

Comment: You might want to look at [the documentation for `split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: And don't use a name like `str` or you'll mask the built-in.

Comment: can you show an actual example and not only your description?

Comment: Probably want a [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using regular expressions

```
import re

your_string = "1234aOUTPUTb5678"
output_pattern = ".*a(.*)b"

output_match = re.search(output_pattern,your_string)
output = output_match.group(1)

print output
>>>"OUTPUT"
```

You will need to replace "a" and "b" with what they literally are though as I don't think you'd be using them as identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out thanks to the input I got from @Twitchykid and @TigerhawkT3:

```
import re

string_to_separate = "... a OUTPUT b ... a OUTPUT b ... a OUTPUT b ..."
string_pattern = ".*a (.*) b.*"
sep = "..."

separated_string = string_to_separate(sep)

for i in range(len(string_to_separate)):
    output_match = re.search(string_pattern, separated_string[i])
    if output.match: #if it exists
        output = output_match.group(1)
        print output
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes work well for this

```
import re

input_string = "a1234b cd a32b blah"
pattern = re.compile("a(.*?)b") #nongreedy so it matches only to the first b, not the last b.

output = pattern.findall(input_string) #this way, I can find all occurrences
print(output)

#['1234', '32']
```